# How do convert a vector made of vectors in R to a single vector?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, vector

I'm working a baseball analysis program that gets data from the internet from multiple web-pages. To simplify my work I used for loops to go page by page and gather all of the data I need into a vector. Like so:

```
player_html <- c()
for(i in 1:28){
  player_html[[i]] <- html_nodes(...)
}
players <- c()
for(i in 1:28){
  players[[i]] <- html_text(...)
```

This examples shows how it goes through 28 different web-pages and pulls out the name of 50 players per page. Once the code is done compiling the "players" variable is listed in the Global Environment as a "List of 28" but each of the 28 spots is filled with no more than 50 names. I would like for it to be a list of 1400 instead of 28 so I can place it into a data frame and stop R from returning an error stating "arguments imply differing number of rows."

Comment: You can `unlist(players)` to return a vector of all entries from the `list`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dataframe of all of your results directly in your for loop, appending the additional results to your output dataframe each iteration. Like so:

```
results <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol=2))
colnames(results) <- c("playername", "page")
player_html <- c()
currnames <- c()

for(i in 1:28){
  html_text() <-  html_nodes(...)
  currnames <- html_text()
  results <- rbind(results, data.frame(playername=currnames, page=i))
}
```